# Displaying Ratio unicode character in putty

Tags: putty, unicode

I'm wondering if this could be a putty bug.
I can't get displayed properly Unicode Character 'RATIO' (U+2236) https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2236/index.htm

Basically it should look like a colon but in putty to me it's just displayed as square. I started from default putty configuration and then tried various settings with Window/Appearance, Window/Translation or locales and environment variables such as terminal. Always the same issue on various windows systems.
I have also the same issue with MobaXterm which I think shares putty terminal code (reported to their support and waiting for response).
This bug would not bother me if not the fact that this character is used in some Midnight Commander compilations/configurations as a separator between hours and minutes in time modification column.

[image]

On the other hand Windows Terminal displays this character with no problems. Also no issues on Mac terminal.

Comment: Have you tried different fonts? Most likely the font you use doesn't have the glyph for this.

Comment: Yes, different fonts is the first thing I tried. Actually I tried also the 'Consolas'  font which is used by default by Windows Terminal. Is this character displayed properly in your putty?

Comment: I don't use Windows at home so I cannot check. On my Debian desktop the character shows correctly.

Comment: But I agree with some fonts putty displays 'Ratio' character correctly. I tried some of those listed here https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2236/fontsupport.htm such as Cambria Math and it looks good in putty. But they are completely unsuitable for text terminal. On the other hand windows terminal displays this character correctly still using fixed width fonts such as Lucida Console, Consoles, Courier New, Ubuntu Mono. In Windows Terminal all these fonts display 'Ratio' character properly and at the same time putty fails to display correctly using these fonts. This is really weird.

Comment: In Windows console (`cmd.exe`), the `DejaVu Sans Mono` font renders `∶`  _RATIO_ character properly; try Windows terminal instead of `cmd` if apply.

Comment: As I have already explained I have no issues with this character in Windows Terminal. I have a problem with having it displayed properly in putty. Does it work well for you in putty? If so can you please provide a download link for this font? I don't think it's available in Windows by default.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://serverfault.com/a/475930/202575)?

Comment: I have not tried setting German locale but I have tried various other locale settings as well as various locale charset settings (including UTF8) in putty.Is this character (U+2236) properly displayed in your putty?

Comment: So it looks like the character in question (Ratio) is not present in console fonts that I checked (Lucida Console, Consolas, Courier New, Ubuntu Mono) and PuTTY does not seem support to support at the moment font fallback https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-font-fallback while the other apps that I checked (notepad, Windows Terminal) do support it and thats why they display it correctly and PuTTY does not.